# How do I disable the left CTRL on Ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard, startup

How do I disable the left CTRL on Ubuntu 13.10?

Actually I can do it already. All I need to run is

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 37 = "
```

The problem I have is this only works if I run it from the terminal *after* my machjine has booted. I really want this run on bootup.

I've tried including the command in a few places:

- /etc/rc.local
- ~/i3/config (I use the i3 window manager)

None of them work.

Any help greatfully recieved :)

Answer (score 2):

Based on [this discussion](https://faq.i3wm.org/question/490/using-caps-lock-as-mod-key/), I think this should work:

1. Create `~/.Xmodmap` file with content:

   ```
   keycode 37 =
   ```
2. Create `~/.xinitrc` with content:

   ```
   # load custom map
   xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap
   ```
3. Make `~/.xinitrc` executable:

   ```
   chmod +x ~/.xinitrc
   ```

Normally, the clean solution to do this kind of thing is to use the keyboard settings of your desktop manager or window manager. But I'm not sure if `i3` really has such setting or not. It looks like an interesting window manager, I might try it soon and come back to this if I find a better solution.

Comment: +1 for the `.Xmodmap` but the OP uses the `i3` window manager, it's not a desktop environment so I doubt it will have this kind of setting.

Answer (score 1):

The thing about xmodmap is that it only pertains to programs running under X; it doesn't affect e.g. the console or a non-X window manager.

In order to remap the keyboard on an earlier level, `loadkeys` is what you want. It uses the keymaps (usually in `/lib/kbd/keymaps/`) corresponding to the physical keyboard you're using. Usually you set this up when installing the system so that it uses a map appropriate to your keyboard.

I've not actually done this recently, but here's how it *should* work if I've got it right:

1 First, dump the current keymap to a file:

```
dumpkeys > /etc/sysconfig/localkeymap.map
```

2 Take a backup of that file in case something goes wrong here.

3 Edit that file to change what you want changed, e.g. `keycode 37 =`.

4 Verify that it works with `loadkeys /etc/sysconfig/localkeymap.map`

5 If it works as expected, add the `loadkeys` command to a suitable start script.
 If it doesn't work, use `loadkeys` on the backup file you created in step 2.